# How to change brightness of video of a gstreamer pipeline dynamically

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am trying below code to change brightness of a video pipeline. I can see the video but brightness never changes although I am trying to change it every 60 seconds. Any idea what I am missing ?

```
static gboolean broadcasting_timeout_cb (gpointer user_data)
{
GstElement *vaapipostproc = NULL;
vaapipostproc = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(broadcasting_pipeline),  
"postproc");

if (vaapipostproc == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to get vaapipostproc from broadcasting 
pipeline\n");
    return TRUE;
}

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (vaapipostproc), "brightness", -1.0, NULL);
fprintf(stderr, "brightness changed by -1.0\n");
return TRUE;
}


main() {
//pipeline code goes here and  then below code comes //

broadcasting_pipeline = gst_parse_launch (compl_streaming_pipe, &error);
if (!broadcasting_pipeline) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", error->message);
    exit (1);
}
loop_broadcasting = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
g_timeout_add_seconds (60, broadcasting_timeout_cb, loop_broadcasting); 

gst_element_set_state (broadcasting_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
g_main_loop_run(loop_broadcasting);
// rest of the code for main function comes here
}
```

Comment: Can you run a simple command line pipeline using videobalance plugin, to verify this fact: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videobalance brightness=1 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink`

Comment: could you try g_object_set (G_OBJECT (vaapipostproc), "brightness", (gfloat)-1.0, NULL); . Also if this doesnt work could you try setting up brightness property in main() itself with values -1 and 1 and check if there is any difference in video.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that vaapipostproc properties like brightness etc can't be change dynamically during runtime !!

However, I found videobalance element works as suggested by Millind Deore. But videobalance is causing cpu usage to be too high and becoming bottleneck for streaming pipeline.

So, I tried with glcolorbalance which is same like videobalance but it is uses gpu for brightness conversion.

Here is my experiment goes :

If I use below pipeline then I can broadcast to youtube  successfully:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=Recorded_live_streaming_on__2018_01_20___13_56_33.219076__-0800.flv ! decodebin name=demux ! queue ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! glupload ! glcolorconvert ! gldownload ! video/x-raw ! vaapih264enc dct8x8=true cabac=true rate-control=cbr bitrate=8192 keyframe-period=60 max-bframes=0 ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location="rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/XXXXX live=1" demux. ! queue ! progressreport ! audioconvert ! audiorate ! audioresample ! faac bitrate=128000 ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! mux.
```

error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'vaapiencodeh264-0': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"(GstVaapiDisplayGLX)\ vaapidisplayglx1";
Got context from element 'gldownloadelement0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"(GstGLDisplayX11)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Redistribute latency...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
progressreport0 (00:00:05): 4 / 1984 seconds ( 0.2 %)
progressreport0 (00:00:10): 9 / 1984 seconds ( 0.5 %)
progressreport0 (00:00:15): 14 / 1984 seconds ( 0.7 %)
progressreport0 (00:00:20): 19 / 1984 seconds ( 1.0 %)

However, if I use glcolorbalance in this pipeline then it gives me following error and I cannot stream to youtube any more:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=Recorded_live_streaming_on__2018_01_20___13_56_33.219076__-0800.flv ! decodebin name=demux ! queue ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! glupload ! glcolorbalance ! glcolorconvert ! gldownload ! video/x-raw ! vaapih264enc dct8x8=true cabac=true rate-control=cbr bitrate=8192 keyframe-period=60 max-bframes=0 ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink sync=true async=true location="rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/XXXXX live=1" demux. ! queue ! progressreport ! audioconvert ! audiorate ! audioresample ! faac bitrate=128000 ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! mux.
```

error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'vaapiencodeh264-0': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"(GstVaapiDisplayGLX)\ vaapidisplayglx1";
Got context from element 'gldownloadelement0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"(GstGLDisplayX11)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Redistribute latency...
***WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:demux: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
./grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:demux:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named demux to some pad of GstQueue named queue0***
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

It seems like glcolorbalanc is causing decodebin not to link with vaapih264enc since it is the only difference between above pipeline.

I am new to gstreamer and Can any one tell me what is wrong with 2nd pipeline and why linking is failing ?